# Does the destination computer of a Remote Desktop Connection count as a Remote Desktop Session Host? (in terms of GPO configuration)

Tags: active-directory, group-policy, remote-desktop, rdp, remote-desktop-services

**For example -**  If you open a Remote Desktop Connection to **Dets-PC** likes this:

["Normal" Remote Desktop Connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LocD4.png) **Note:** Dest-PC is just a normal Out-of-the-box Windows Server with no additional Windows-Features installed

Is the Remote Desktop Connection to **Dets-PC** effected by Group Policies set in:

*Computer Configuration\Policies\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Remote Desktop Services\Remote Desktop Session Host*

**AND** does Dest-PC calssify as a Remote Desktop Session Host (RDHS)?

---

**If the Connection is effected by those GPOs:**
That should mean if i activate a Group Policy, such as forced Network Level Authentication in
*...\Remote Desktop Session Host\Security* it will effect a regular Remote Desktop Connection, correct?

If Remote Desktop Connections aren't effected by the Group Policies mentioned above, how can they be configured?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, some of the settings do, such as the setting in your example.

Other settings may not. RD Connection Broker and Licensing would not apply to workstations.